# Query elasticsearch with multiple numeric ranges

Tags: elasticsearch

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "log_path": "message_notification.log"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "numeric_range": {
          "time_taken": {
            "gte": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "distinct_user_ids": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "user_id"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have to run this query 20 times as i want to know notification times above each of the following thresholds- `[10,30,60,120,240,300,600,1200..]`. Right now, i am running a loop and making 20 queries for fetching this.

Is there a more sane way to query elasticsearch once and get ranges that fall into these thresholds respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want is a "[range aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-range-aggregation.html)".

Here is the possible query where you can add more range or alter them -

`{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "log_path": "message_notification.log"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "intervals": {
      "range": {
        "field": "time_taken",
        "ranges": [
          {
            "to": 50
          },
          {
            "from": 50,
            "to": 100
          },
          {
            "from": 100
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "distinct_user_ids": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "user_id"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`